# Touch event handling on android parent and child custom views

Tags: android, touch, swipe, custom-view, gesturedetector

today I got a problem with touch event handling on android custom views.In this case i have created parent view call weekview and chiled call weekdayview.i want implement touch event like singleTap,LongPress in child view only and when i swipe on parent or child i wanna scroll    parent view.when i implement touch event in both view it dose not work.

[image]

can anyone help me on this.It's really helpful to me.
Thank you

Comment: I think if the touch event is on child view, the parent view will never get notified. So better use GestureDetector, inside your Child view, onTouchEvent, you dispatch the event to gesture, and deal it on parent view.

Comment: I use GestureDetector in both view scrolling part is done on parent view and it is OK.but i want do some thing on child view.I return false in onDown method in child view.then scroll parent is working and touch event on child view dose not work

Answer (score 2):

```
class ChildView extends View {


    public void setGestureDetector (GestureDetector g)
    {
        gesture = g;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent (....)
    {
        return gesture.onTouchEvent (....); // touch event will dispatch to gesture
    } 
}

class ParentView extends View implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {

    gesture = new GestureDetector (this);

    child = new ChildView (...);
    child.setGestureDetector (gesture);

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent (..)
    {
       // handle your parent touch event here
    }

    public boolean onDown (...)
    {
       return true;
    }

    public boolean fling (...) 
    {
       // here to handle child view fling
    }


}
```

This is peso-code (not real android java) to show you the concept to use GestureDetector, you can deal with all events from your child view in your parent View. As I tested on my android phone, onTouchEvent in ChildView didn't recognize ACTION_UP very well, so even you swipe your Child View, sometimes fling will not work (it depends on ACTION_UP).

So if you want to write more accurate swipe on your Child View, better write your owen Gesture Detect class, and in your ChildView, you can do this -

```
float oldX;
float distanceX;

public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event...)
{
     if (event.getAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        // handle down
        oldX = event.getX ();
     }

     if (event.getAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE {
        // handle move
        distanceX = event.getX() - oldX; // more accurate

        gesture.onSwipe (distanceX); // your own gesture class
     }


}
```

Comment: I use something very close to this implementation.I have created gesture detector on parent and child.Is that way different from you method.

Comment: I think the child view will dispatch event to your parentview, so you can deal with fling (swipe), also in your parent view ontouchevent, you can deal with swipe too, return true in your onDown event. I have done the simliar one, and I know fling have a bug, sometimes in my android phone, the onTouchEvent can't recognize ACTION_UP very well, so fling will not trigger this time.

Answer (score 0):

Set your swipe velocity (to detect user's intention to swipe) and override the onTouchEvent() in your child view.
Here, call super.onTouchEvent() and return, which calls your parent view. Handle the events in the parent view.